# iOS - Inapp purchase - subscriptions

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I'm having in-app purchase subscriptions in my app. I'm able to integrate and make subscriptions successfully. There are 3 different subscriptions, monthly, quarter and yearly.
So if user subscribes to monthly user can use that feature for 30 days. There's no server in my case. Only availability of some features will be activated/deactivated according to subscription.

When ever the app starts, i want to check whether user paid for subscription or not. If I'm maintaining some bool value in subscriptions, what if the user has deactivated the subscriptions from settings? How can I detect whether the subscriptions are valid or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to post the receipt back to apple server and from the response we receive, we can identify the expiry date. Then I'll know whether the subscription is expired or renewed etc.
Visit [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

You can add counter and add that counter value in a database that must be inside your app. Whenever user tries to access subscriptions you can verify from the database.

Comment: I think you are talking about regular inapp purchases. For subscriptions, two things has to be considered. 1. Is the subscription active or inactive. 2. Is the subscription renewed (automatically or manual) or not. So if user deactivated his subscription, checking it with local database wont help. At the same time if subscription is not renewed, checking with local database won't help.